# How can I increase timeout for HTTParty post method in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty

I have a method in rails to send post requests to a third party API. The code looks similar to the following:

```
data = HTTParty.post("url",
  :headers=> {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'},
  :body=> { update => true, first_name => "name" }
)
```

With this, after exactly one minute, the process is terminated with the following error.

```
<Net::HTTPGatewayTimeOut 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT readbody=true>
```

Comment: reference link: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#attribute-i-write_timeout

Answer (score 19):

Set the default by:

```
module HTTParty
  default_timeout your_preferred_timeout
end
```

or set it individually by:

```
data = HTTParty.post("url",
  headers: {"Content-Type" => "application/json"},
  body: {update => true, first_name => "name"},
  timeout: your_preferred_timeout
)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try

```
 data = HTTParty.post("url",
  headers: {"Content-Type" => "application/json"},
  body: {update => true, first_name => "name"},
  open_timeout: 0.5,
  write_timeout:1,
  read_timeout:3
)
```

also you can reference
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#attribute-i-write_timeout

Comment: is it suitable for httparty?  It's Net::HTTP

Comment: it is. httparty